# How can I draw a conceptual dependency for the statement "Place all ingredients in a bowl and mix thoroughly"?

Tags: knowledge-representation, conceptual-dependency

I stumbled across a question asking to draw a conceptual dependency for the following statement:

> Place all ingredients in a bowl and mix thoroughly

My attempt so far

[image: My working]

Explanation: Both the sender and recipient are the same, except that the states of their contents are different.

Something feels like it isn't right. I would appreciate if you could correct errors, if any.

Answer (score 1):

As it's two clauses ("place in bowl" and "mix"), I would actually use two separate CD structures. The first one is a PTRANS (not ATRANS, as you don't change ownership, but location); the second one is a bit trickier.

*Mix* can be paraphrased as *stir*, or *move around*. You would typically do this with a spoon or similar implement. I would do it as a PROPEL with the instrument spoon and the object the ingredients. PROPEL, according to Schank (1975) is the "application of a physical force to an object".

So the first one is:

```
(PTRANS
  (ACTOR *you*)
  (OBJECT "all ingredients")
  (TO "bowl"))
```

And the second is:

```
(PROPEL
  (ACTOR *you*)
  (OBJECT "ingredients")
  (INSTRUMENT "a spoon")
  (DIRECTION "circular"))
```

It's debatable if you PROPEL the ingredients with the instrument spoon, or you PROPEL the object spoon with the target/location/direction ingredients.

If you draw them in a graphical representation, you can have both ACTs leading off the shared actor '*you*'; or you could have them as separate graphs linked by 'then' or some other indicator of sequentiality.

Schank, Roger (1975) *The primitive ACTs of conceptual dependency*, Proc of 1975 workshop on theoretical issues in natural language processing, 34-37